# MongoDB Use Linq for Text Search

Tags: mongodb, linq, full-text-search, driver

Is there a way to query Text index using the LINQ Drivers?
Like :

```
db.Sample.find({$text: { $search: "\"MA\" \"Springfield\""}})
```

but in LINQ

Thanks